# how to manually calculate code coverage percentage for path coverage?

Tags: testing, code-coverage, white-box-testing

I am manually creating the white-box testing for our system and I have issues with automated coverage testing tools. This is a Java-based system.

> Path coverage % = (Total paths exercised / total number of paths in
>   program) * 100

I was able to determine the total paths exercised but I don't know how to get the total number of paths in the program.

Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Comment: You might want to define "path", or show how you determined total paths exercised as a way of showing your definition of path. At least by some definitions of path, most useful programs have a very high number of paths. For example, are three paths different if they differ only in going through the same loop 0, 1 and 2 times?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate path coverage for code it could be not representative due to high cyclomatic complexity. It's more useful to use decision coverage to calculate all if/else in code and use path coverage for a business logic and user scenarios.